# read dates from a text file and convert - what kind of datamodel?

Tags: java, mysql, data-conversion

i need to read a textfile in java and convert it. The reading of a textfile is simple and not the problem. But i dont know how to convert or how to store the data. The file has some dates for example:

```
2021-06-17, User A
2021-06-18, User A
2021-06-19, User A
2021-06-20, User A
2021-06-24, User A
2021-06-25, User A
2021-06-17, User B
```

At the end i need this result:

```
2021-06-17, 2021-06-20, User A
2021-06-24, 2021-06-25, User A
2021-06-17, 2021-06-17, User B
```

What is the easiest way?

I can insert the data from the textfile in a mysql table, order it by user and date and loop through the table to create from-date, to-date and user.

But i dont like to use mysql. Because i dont need this data in the table after converting.

I am looking for an option to solve it in plain java. But how can i store and sort the data? An array i think wont work because i only have a key and a value. A Hashmap either. Is there no type like a table?

What would you suggest to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest modelling "the information in a line of source data" as a class, then you can create a list of those as you read the file. Then you can process that data however you want. (It's not really clear how you got from your source data to your end result, but that's a separate matter...)

Comment: *At the end i need this result:* Why? describe precise joining criteria. And how does this question is related to MySQL?

Comment: I need to get the the first date and the last date without any missing dates between. I see in the example the 2021-06-19 is missing for user a. So i have single dates. and i need to get first an last date of a series for each user.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a TreeSet

So the structure will look like

`Map<String, TreeSet<LocalDate>>`
Where key is `user` (`String`) and value is sorted `dates` (`Treeset`)

While reading, you can simply insert the records in the treeset, and later on, when you start traversal, you will get the sorted dates by user, which you can  use later.

You may go through this article for more on treesets - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/treeset-in-java-with-examples/

Comment: Thanks will the TreeSet order the Dates by default? I havent used a TreeSet before.

Comment: Treesets are ordered by default. Check this article - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/treeset-in-java-with-examples/